# How to remove parenthesis and inside text in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some species names + parenthesis and a number inside + some text, like : "species name(2) V1", which are present in dataframe$species_name.
I need to remove it with gsub so it only returns "species name" and another to return "species name V1".
Thanks in advance!

I've searched around and nothing couldn't find a regular expression pattern for this, in R at least. I could only find code to remove the parenthesis. I'm too noob to know how to remove the rest.

Comment: In gsub and other regex you can identify special characters with a double escape, something like `gsub("\\(\\d+\\)", "", names(DF))` (not  sure if that covers your case, since the question doesn't include a reproducible example)

Comment: `sub("(^[^(]*)\\(.*$", "\\1", dataframe$species_name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two regexp solve the two problems in the question.

```
s <- "species name(2) V1"

sub("(^[^(]*)\\(.*$", "\\1", s)
#[1] "species name"

sub("\\([^)]*\\)", "", s)
#[1] "species name V1"
```

Now apply them to the column of interest.

Comment: It's exactly this.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned `gsub()`, I assumed you wanted to stick with base R.

Here I create two new variables based on some randomly generated species names that I think match your request.

"(" is a special character and therefore must escaped with "\" but because "\" is a special character itself you must escape it with another "\" resulting the the "\\"s.

"." matches any one character and "*" is a quantifier that says match 0 or more.

"$" indicates the end of the string.

[0-9] matches a single integer.

"+" is another quantifier that says to match one or more.

Thus we have:

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(species_name = paste0("species ", 
                                       sample(LETTERS, 10), 
                                       " name(", 
                                       sample(1:10), 
                                       ") V", 
                                       sample(1:10)))

df$species_name1 <- gsub("\\(.*$", "", df$species_name)

df$species_name2 <- gsub("\\([0-9]*\\)", "", df$species_name)

df
```

Which produces:

```
            species_name  species_name1      species_name2
1   species Q name(9) V4 species Q name  species Q name V4
2   species E name(5) V5 species E name  species E name V5
3   species A name(6) V7 species A name  species A name V7
4   species J name(4) V9 species J name  species J name V9
5   species D name(2) V8 species D name  species D name V8
6  species R name(8) V10 species R name species R name V10
7   species Z name(3) V2 species Z name  species Z name V2
8   species O name(7) V3 species O name  species O name V3
9   species G name(1) V6 species G name  species G name V6
10 species V name(10) V1 species V name  species V name V1
```